# How to get grid area to apply to class?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been trying to position a logo in the second column of a grid I made for the banner of a website, however no matter how I position it or what args I give "grid-area:" it stays in the first column. What is the reason for this?

**HTML file:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random Company</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" 
href="./photos/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="logo"><img src="./photos/logo2.png"/></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS file:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    display: grid;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template: 100% / 10% 10% 60% 20%;
    background-color: #e8d0a9;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.logo img{
    position: relative;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 1 / span 1;
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong, instead of `.logo img` try just `.logo`
`.logo img` means that the object you're referring to is both of class logo and is of type img,  while in your html they're nested.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    display: grid;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template: 100% / 10% 10% 60% 20%;
    background-color: #e8d0a9;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.logo{
    position: relative;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 1 / span 1;
    height: 80%;
    width: auto;
    background-color:red
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random Company</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" 
href="./photos/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="logo"><img src="./photos/logo2.png"/></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```